# On Scrolling Check Boxes are getting Unchecked or Vice versa in a RecyclerView

Tags: android, checkbox, android-recyclerview

I have a check box in RecyclerView Adapter's View Item.
When scrolling, some check boxes are getting checked and some are getting unchecked.
I have taken help from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42159900/checkboxes-gets-unchecked-in-recyclerview-upon-scrolling) and [this](https://mobikul.com/get-selected-checkboxes-recyclerview/)
But I am unable to find the exact solution to this.

Here is my code

```
public class AllContactsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AllContactsAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<PhoneContactsModel> listOfContacts = new ArrayList<>();
    PhoneContactsModel phoneContactsModel;

    private ArrayList<PhoneContactsModel> copyOfListOfContacts = new ArrayList<>();

    public AllContactsAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<PhoneContactsModel> listOfContacts) {
        this.context = context;
        this.listOfContacts = listOfContacts;
        // copyOfListOfContacts.addAll(listOfContacts);
    }

    @Override
    public AllContactsAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.
                adapter_load_allusers_contacts_listitem, parent, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final AllContactsAdapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        Log.d("tag", "adapter========3");
        phoneContactsModel = listOfContacts.get(position);
        holder.name.setText(phoneContactsModel.getContactName());
        holder.phoneNumber.setText(phoneContactsModel.getContactNumber());
        holder.checkBox.setSelected(phoneContactsModel.isChecked());

        holder.contactLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if (holder.checkBox.isChecked()) {
                    phoneContactsModel.setChecked(false);
                    holder.checkBox.setChecked(false);
                    copyOfListOfContacts.remove(listOfContacts.get(position));

                } else {
                    phoneContactsModel.setChecked(true);
                    holder.checkBox.setChecked(true);
                    copyOfListOfContacts.add(listOfContacts.get(position));
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return listOfContacts.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder  {

        private TextView name, phoneNumber;
        private CheckBox checkBox;
        private LinearLayout contactLayout;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            name = view.findViewById(R.id.contactNameId);
            phoneNumber = view.findViewById(R.id.contactNumberId);
            checkBox = view.findViewById(R.id.checkBoxId);
            contactLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.contactLayoutId);
        }
    }
}
```

For example, I have checked 1,2,3 items in list. When I scrolled down and come up , then 13 is checked and 2 is unchecked along with other some items.Please help me.

Any solution is appreciated.

Comment: You must update the `phoneContactsModel` whenever user check/uncheck the checkbox.

Comment: @MonishKamble can You tell me Clearly?

Answer (score 1):

A simple way arround is do not use `OnCheckedChangeListener` just set `OnClickListener` on Check box . Move checkBox onclick inside **ViewHolder** class.

```
 public class ViewHolder1 extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    CheckBox checkBox;
    public ViewHolder1(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        checkBox = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
        checkBox.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(getAdapterPosition()!=-1) {
            phoneContactsModel.get(getAdapterPosition()).setChecked(!phoneContactsModel.get(getAdapterPosition()).isChecked());
            notifyItemChanged(getAdapterPosition());
        }
    }
}
```

And

```
public void onBindViewHolder(final AllContactsAdapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.checkBox.setChecked(phoneContactsModel.isChecked());
}
```

Comment: This should work if you have done it above way i think . Use `setChecked(phoneContactsModel.isChecked())` instead of  `setSelected(phoneContactsModel.isChecked())`. and remove `CheckedChangeListener`.

Comment: again getting unnecessary check boxes are checked

Comment: Thats maybe because you still have some other code to change checked status . Check in `onBindViewHolder` where else you are changing the state .

Answer (score 0):

**notify your adapter.**

```
 holder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
            phoneContactsModel.setChecked(b);
           //notifyItemChanged(position);(if you want to notify change in single item)
           //or
           //notifyDataSetChanged();(if you want to notify change in all) 

        }
    });
```

**no need to  use this line of code twice**

```
    holder.checkBox.setSelected(phoneContactsModel.isChecked());
```

**//this section seems buggy i assume you want to add the item to the list when ever the check box is checked and remove it from the list when ever the check box is unchecked.**

```
  holder.contactLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if (phoneContactsModel.isChecked()) {
                    holder.checkBox.setSelected(false);
                    copyOfListOfContacts.remove(listOfContacts.get(position));

                } else {
                    holder.checkBox.setSelected(true);
                    copyOfListOfContacts.add(listOfContacts.get(position));

                }
            }
        }
```

);

Answer (score 0):

```
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        final PhoneContactsModel phoneContactsModel = listOfContacts.get(position);
        holder.name.setText(phoneContactsModel.getContactName());
        holder.phoneNumber.setText(phoneContactsModel.getContactNumber());
        holder.checkBox.setChecked(/* gets value from the modal */ phoneContactsModel.isChecked());

        holder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean value) {

                if (compoundButton.isPressed()) {
                    holder.checkBox.setChecked(value);
                    // set the value into the modal.
                    phoneContactsModel.setChecked(value);
                    if (value) {
                        copyOfListOfContacts.remove(phoneContactsModel);
                    } else {
                        copyOfListOfContacts.add(phoneContactsModel);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Change your `onBindViewHolder` method like this. There won't be any unnecessary checks.

Comment: But I am getting checks after each 10 items. for example If  I check first item then 11 th, 21 st, 31st... items are getting checked.

Comment: Yes, I updated the Adapter class by  myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); method.

Comment: I mean, can you update the question with your complete adapter class.
I think there is something wrong out there.

Comment: I have added adapter class .please check it.

Comment: Did you try removing the `OnClickListener` and change to `OnCheckedChangeListener` like i have answered ?

Comment: I want action for Linear Layout.

Comment: you can do that inside the `OnCheckedChangeListener `.
See my updated answer and replace your `onBindViewHolder` like the above one.

Comment: look like it is only for check box click action

Comment: You can try that out and confirm whether the unnecessary checks are occuring or not and then can have your own implementation. Rest is upto you.